# Error while generating CSR and creating .pfx file

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm using xenroll to generate CSR, send to CA, create pfx file and make it password protected. It's working in one of the environments but in another I'm getting an error...

My app is hosted on IIS and on webpage I get waiting message and after some time it gives me session time out error (which is normal behavior of any asp.net app), it seems that it displays some popup window and that is hidden somewhere which is not visible to us.

> Description:
>
> Application popup: Security Warning : You are about to install a certificate from a certification authority (CA) claiming to represent:
>
> My CA Name
>
> Windows cannot validate that the certificate is actually from "My CA Name". You should confirm its origin by contacting "My CA Name". The following number will assist you in this process:
>
> Thumbprint (sha1):
>
> Warning:
>
> If you install this root certificate, Windows will automatically trust any certificate issued by this CA. Installing a certificate with an unconfirmed thumbprint is a security risk. If you click "Yes" you acknowledge this risk.
>
> Do you want to install this certificate?
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at go.microsoft.com/.../events.asp.

Any idea?

Comment: What code do you have currently.. can you show us what you have as well as the line in your code where the error is being generated / Thrown..?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install a self-signed certificate.

Comment: My Code was like this  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c.aspx?PageIndex=6#comments   - and we resolved it by installing CA root certificate into IIS local user trust store and that resolved my problem..thanks GregS